# Unity remote debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm unable to attach the Visual Studio debugger for Unity to the **remote** Unity server build (development, script debugging). I've tried both Linux and Windows.

**Steps: Debug -> Attach Unity Debugger -> Input IP**

I'm sure IP and port are correct. The firewall on the remote side is also not the issue.

As for Linux, my script on the remote IP event prints out: PlayerConnection accepted from [2??.??.6?.?02] handle:0x7

But the debugger in Visual Studio just won't attach. It seems it starts building, but won't attach without printing any error or other indication of what is going on.

Local debugging works fine.

How can I make it work?